# Is an alien (from outside earth) a someone or a something?

Tags: word-usage

If I am pointing across the room and there is an animal (let's forget about writing animals in the context of humans - no Animal Farm references) - I would point and say, "there is something over there."

In that context, if I said, "there is someone over there"... well that would be odd and wrong.

However if there is an alien across the room and I point is it a someone or a something?

Comment: Might it be better to ask on [stackexchange worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)? If it oozes, like *The Blob,* I'd say a something. If it asks  (with a British accent) to see your leader, perhaps someone.

Comment: If X would be insulted at being called something, he, she, it or whatever is a someone.  And if h,s,i,w came in his or whatever's own spaceship, definintely a someone.

Comment: @ab2 I would agree that a self-aware alien would be a person (and, therefore, someone) but there is no guarantee that alien biology would be equivalent to ours in any way so the use of gendered pronouns would be highly inappropriate. The most appropriate pronoun is probably "they".

Comment: I thought whatever covered it.

Comment: I am a little lost at why this would be closed.   There are literally a thousand questions asking "what is the best word to use" or what word has this meaning 99% of them are opinion.   WTH

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you consider the line between intelligent life and just animals. Overall it depends on your own perception of the alien standing before you.

I'd also like to mention a common trope in many horror movies and even some other pieces of media where someone will say:

> "There's someone, or something..."

to build suspense about what the person (or thing) really is. Also, I'd also have to add that if what you're pointing at is ambiguous (it's in shadow, it's around a corner, etc.) you'd probably be more likely to say **something** rather than **someone** as you need to know if something is an intelligent lifeform before calling it the latter.

We can only really answer this question concretely when humans have found an easy and reliable way to tell apart intelligent life from other lifeforms. You may want to keep waiting :D